# Are nested ifs equals to and logic?

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, logic

I wonder whether these two Python codes are **always** the same or not.

```
if condition_1:
    if condition_2:
        some_process
```

and

```
if condition_1 and condition_2:
    some_process
```

I searched but did not find any specific answer to this question. So, for example, you are trying to evaluate a variable, but you cannot determine if that variable exists. So, in the first place, you should check variable existence. Can we use the variable existence check with "and" logic alongside with our evaluation? Is it **always** applicable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are **always** equivalent. In fact, they compile down to the *exact same* bytecode, and only differ in some metadata<sup>1</sup>:

```
# Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0]
# Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
# IPython 7.31.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: def v1():
   ...:     if x:
   ...:         if y:
   ...:             pass
   ...: 

In [2]: def v2():
   ...:     if x and y:
   ...:         pass
   ...: 

In [3]: import dis

In [4]: dis.dis(v1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7 (to 14)

  3           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (y)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9 (to 18)

  4           8 NOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

  2     >>   14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE

  3     >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]: dis.dis(v2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7 (to 14)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (y)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9 (to 18)

  3           8 NOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

  2     >>   14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE

In [6]: v1.__code__.co_code == v2.__code__.co_code
Out[6]: True
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Namely, the `co_name`, `co_linetable`, and `co_lnotab` attributes of the functions' code objects, which do not affect the execution of the code. See the output of</sub>

```
import types
print( 
    {
        attr: (
            getattr(v1.__code__, attr),
            getattr(v2.__code__, attr),
        )
        for attr in dir(types.CodeType) if "co_" in attr
    }
)
```

<sub>for a detailed comparison of the functions' respective code objects.</sub>

Comment: But, as the comments mentioned, the statements are getting checked from left to right. So, It is better to mention that they are the same if the cond_1 comes first in the "and" logic. Is it true?

Comment: you beat me to it :-)